# Where is configure NAT?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, webserver, nat

I want to test my asp.net web project. I already access website successful from the same network(in the same network I type in web browser: 192.168.0.188/SmartHotel). Now I want to access from another network. I need to configure NAT so I can access from another computer on another network. I have the modem router D-link dsl-526e, I check on http://canyouseeme.org, the ip address of modem router is 113.181.xxx.xxx. A TP-Link Wireless tl-wr841n. The TP-Link Wireless connected to the modem router. The ip addres of TP-Link Wireless is 192.168.0.1. A computer contain webserver, the computer connected to the TP-Link Wireless and I set IP static for the computer is: 192.168.0.188. My question is where I configure NAT, on modem router or TP-Link Wireless? Please show me how to configure NAT. Thanks you.

Comment: Why do you think you need NAT anyway?

Comment: @FleetCommand Because I think when I type ip address of modem router or tp-link wireless, it will directly to my website. I mean I can access website if I type 113.181.xxx.xxx/SmartHotel  in web browser. I'm not sure.

Comment: Then go make sure. And be sure to setup a proper server first because the default testing servers that coming with ASP.NET development packages only accept traffic from the local computer. NAT or no NAT.

Comment: As I know, use NAT to navigate to a addrees, and webserver independent  NAT or no NAT

Comment: In proper English, please! I didn't understand anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the page to configure Port Forwarding.  It will probably be in the advanced options section.  Once there, you will need to click on the button that says something like add rule or add service.  Now you must tell it to forward TCP port 80 (HTTP's port) to port 80 on 192.168.0.188.  Then just save and apply it.

Once that is done, you should be able to connect to your site from outside your local network.